# smtplib disconnected when sending multiple emails

Tags: python, email, smtplib

I am trying to use SMTPlib to send emails using python. I can send a single email in the standard way. Now, I want to send multiple emails, and there should be a way to do it without logging in, and quitting the server every time, before sending an email. I tried the following. I wrapped everything in a SendEmail class, and connected to the server in its init() method:

```
class SendEmail:

def __init__(self):
    self.username='username@yahoo.com';
    self.password='password';
    self.server=smtplib.SMTP('smtp.mail.yahoo.com',587);
    self.server.starttls();
    self.server.login(self.username,self.password);
```

Now, I try to use a SendAnEmail() method for the class,to send multiple emails:

```
def SendAnEmail(self,reciever):
    message='blah';

    try:
        self.server.sendmail(self.username,reciever,message);
        print 'Message Sent'
    except:
        self.server.quit();
        self.server=None;
```

When I declare an instant of the class, and call SendAnEmail() for the first time, it works.
When I call it the second time, it gives me an error, saying that the server is disconnected.
Since I have not destroyed the class instance, how is the server getting disconnected?
And what is the way around it. Should I connect,login and quit everytime I send an email?

So, in main function:

```
def main():
    mail0=SendEmail();
    mail0.SendAnEmail('reciever1@yahoo.com');#this works
    time.sleep(60);
    mail0.SendAnEmail('reciever2@yahoo.com');#this does not work
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `time.sleep(60)` - Yahoo won't wait that long (30 seconds?) and will close the connection.

A couple of other things:

1. Python does not need semicolons at the end of a line
2. `sendmail()` accepts a list of recipients so you can send an email to multiple recipients in one go.

Comment: That's the main question I have. Is the SMTPlib connection only for sending a single email?
I am thinking of server.login() as something similar to logging in to read email in a browser, where I login, send a bunch of emails,and remain logged in until I logout.
So server.login() doesn't work like that?

I am aware that Python doesn't "need" semicolons. Its just a CPP habit I have.

Yes, I can do multiple recipients too, but I just want to check why SMTP disconnected between multiple calls to same instance of class?

Comment: Have you actually tried removing the 60 second sleep and then sending multiple emails on the same SMTP instance? You will find that it will work. The SMTP server won't keep your connection open forever, and will close the connection (or log you off) after some time less than 60 seconds if there is no activity - I guess it is around 30 seconds. You can try these simple tests yourself.

Comment: Okay, I tried by changing the 60 second sleep. This works. Thanks a lot.